# WPF: One-way binding on entire DataGrid

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

Is there a way to mark the entire DataGrid as one-way binding?

Comment: To make it behave in a completely non-standard way, of course!  That's the key to good usability, right?   ;)

Comment: Because I'm binding to a set of read-only properties and I'm tired of writing ", Mode=OneWay".

Comment: Maybe you could override default dependency property metadata?

Comment: That sounds interesting, but I'm using INotifyPropertyChanges instead of a dependency property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new class such as OneWayExtension that inherits binding.

```
 public class OneWayExtension : Binding
{
    public OneWayExtension()
        : base()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public OneWayExtension(string path)
        : base(path)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        this.Source = YourSourceOrMakeThisAParameter;
        this.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
    }
}
```

You can then call this by

```
{local:OneWay PathOfData}
```

Comment: Interesting. It looks like I could do a lot of cool stuff using this.

Comment: I find it a great way to set User and App Settings.

One "issue" is XAML editor will complain it cannot find a constructor with one argument.  This has been addressed by MS as Will Not Fix.  You can "work around" it by moving the class to a separate project in the solution, which for Settings doesn't work but for your case it might.  Or if you don't mind the warning (still compiles obviously), ignore it ;)

Comment: That's the kind of patently obvious answer that I could worry over this problem for six months and never find.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is already answered, but can't you just set the binding `Mode` on the DataGrid's `ItemsSource` property to `OneWay`?

Comment: How would you do that? The `ItemsSource` property is an `IEnumerable` and doesn't have a `Mode` property.